# Error en formula excel

Tags: excel, formulas

Hola a todos tengo el siguiente problema tengo esta formula excel `=SI(BG3="ACTIVA      ";"1";SI(BG3="BLOQUEADA   ";"4";"2"))` pero en esa misma necesito agregarle así : `=SI.ERROR(BG3=BH3;"INCONSISTENCIA")`, he intentado agregarlo pero aún así no me funciona, alguien puede ayudarme por favor.

Answer (score 2):

Estás usando mal la función de SI.ERROR.

> [Función
> SI.ERROR](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/funci%C3%B3n-si-error-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611)

LA función SI.ERROR evalúa una expresión y **si esa expresión devuelve un error** entonces es cuando retorna el valor especificado. Si no hay error, devuelve el valor de la expresión.

En tu caso estás evaluando la expresión `BG3=BH3`. Si esto devuelve error entonces devolverá INCONSISTENCIA pero, si no hay error, devolverá VERDADERO o FALSO.

Creo que lo que quieres es combinar todo con SÍES anidados, no necesitas SI.ERROR.

Prueba algo así:

`=SI(BG3=BH3;"INCONSISTENCIA";SI(BG3="ACTIVA ";"1";SI(BG3="BLOQUEADA ";"4";"2")))`